# KafkaUtils API | offset management | Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to manage kafka offsets for exactly once semantics.

Facing problem while creating a direct stream using offset map as follows :

```
val fromOffsets : (TopicAndPartition, Long) = TopicAndPartition(metrics_rs.getString(1), metrics_rs.getInt(2)) -> metrics_rs.getLong(3)

KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder,(String, String)] (ssc,kafkaParams,fromOffsets,messageHandler)
```

here,

```
val messageHandler =
      (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => mmd.message.length
```

And

```
metrics_rs = metricsStatement.executeQuery("SELECT part,off from metrics.txn_offsets where topic='"+t+''' )
```

I guess I am doing something wrong with the declaration style...if you could help.
The compilation error says "too many type arguments for createDirectStream"

Comment: Are you aware of the latest Kafka 0.10+-compatible `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`? I wonder why you use the 5-type 0.8-compatible interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things I see that you're doing wrong.

You need to pass a `Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]`, while currently you have a `Tuple2[TopicAndPartition, Long]`. So you need:

```
val fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long] = 
    Map(TopicAndPartition(metrics_rs.getString(1), 
                          metrics_rs.getInt(2)) -> metrics_rs.getLong(3))
```

You say your return type from `createDirectStream` is a tuple of type `(String, String)`, yet your `messageHandler` value is an `Int`. If you want to return a tuple with key value pairs, you need:

```
val messageHandler: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (String, String) =
  (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mmd.key(), mmd.message())
```

After fixing that, this should compile:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils
              .createDirectStream[String, String,
                      StringDecoder, StringDecoder,
                      (String, String)] (ssc, 
                                         kafkaParams, 
                                         fromOffsets, 
                                         messageHandler)
```

Comment: Yes, i did convert the tuple to Map and the messageHandler but it still isn't compiling.

Comment: Is `kafkaParams` a `Set[String]`?

Comment: It is a Map...

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
                                          "zookeeper.connect" -> KafkaConfig.zookeeperHost,
                                          "group.id" -> KafkaConfig.groupId,
                                          "auto.commit.enable" -> KafkaConfig.autoCommitEnabled,
                                          "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> KafkaConfig.autoCommitInterval,
                                          "bootstrap.servers" -> KafkaConfig.bootstrapServers....)

Comment: @user1521672 Right, my bad. Are you sure you fixed your `messageHandler` properly? What is the error message saying?

Comment: yep...
val messageHandler: (String, String) =
      (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mmd.key(), mmd.message())

The same error "too many type arguments for createDirectStream"

Comment: @user1521672 Again, I've modified `messageHandler`, it needs to be a `Function1[MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (String, String)]`, not a tuple.

Comment: new to scala so could not comprehend your last comment, i m sorry.
If you could elaborate.

Comment: @user1521672 I've modified my answer, see how `messageHandler` is declared now.

Comment: thanks man...
Had one query extending to this...how exactly does the messageHandler works....I mean, we specify the topic, partition and offset value in offsets param from which it can create the stream, so where is the utility of this particular argument...what precisely(and how) is it handling

Comment: @user1521672 I'm not sure I follow your question. What do you mean by *"Where is the utility of this particular argument"*?

Comment: I meant to ask what is the use of messageHandler?

Comment: MessgeHandler is a class which exposes the data from kafka. It has a `key()` and `message()` methods, and some additional information regarding topics and partitions.